# Apologizing to someone

Tags: grammar

I've known for a long time that "She apologizes to him for breaking his vase" is a correct sentence, but if one were to say sorry to another, could that be written as "She has been apologizing to him for breaking his vase", or "She has been apologizing him for breaking his vase"?

Comment: "She apologizes to him for breaking his vase"  is only correct in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how long she's been apologizing.

"She has been" means that she is doing it continually. For instance: "She has been apologizing for breaking the vase for the past five years, but he still hasn't forgiven him."

Or: "She broke the vase this morning and has been apologizing all afternoon."

But if she just apologizes once, "has been" is wrong.

"She apologizes" is *simple present tense*. "She has been" is *present perfect tense*. Suggestion: Review the difference.

Comment: Why 'She has been apologizing'? Why not 'She apologizes'? Both are different in meaning.

Comment: If the apology has already been made, it's _She has apologised_ unless, as Charlie says, she keeps on doing so.